# Is there a worst case implementation of the JVM?

Tags: java, multithreading, memory, synchronization, jvm

The [Java memory model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Memory_Model) makes it clear what can and cannot be assumed about how threads interact through memory. For example, if one thread writes a new value to a field without appropriate synchronization then the new value is not guaranteed to be observable by other threads. In practice, however, other threads might anyhow read the new value in spite of inadequate synchronization, depending on time between write and read, hardware architecture, etc.

This can lead to bugs that are hard to discover and difficult to reproduce. It could therefore be useful to run a java application on a worst case JVM that did absolutely no memory synchronization between threads beyond the guarantees in the [Java memory model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Memory_Model). Does such a worst case JVM implementation exist?

Comment: I thought Microsoft J++ was it.

Comment: You both think are you funny, but are both saying positive things about Sun and Microsoft instead of negative.  It would be best if the JVM always showed the worst case result from the memory model as that would reveal the most bugs, but its not the case right now where most of these bugs are hidden

Comment: Great question. I have thought the same about Swing elements and EDT violations (although clever skins can help here). It would be fantastic if such an intelligent VM was developed. It could go beyond a worst case implementation for memory model, it could actually alert you immediately when another thread accesses a changed reference or primitive.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [Terracotta](http://www.terracotta.org/) to cluster your program. It is incredibly unforgiving around incorrect synchronization (which will become apparent even with only one node in the cluster). This is a **great** question: I've often wanted exactly this ability - I'm surprised there's not a switch in the standard JRE `-XXJMMExtreme`

Terracotta is open-source and free for the basic product.

Answer (score 1):

This might help: http://javapathfinder.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any VM which guarantees worst case behavior all the time, which seems to be what you are asking for.  The situation that you are describing can occur with Sun VMs (as well as many others), but only due to caching issues.  I'm not familiar with a VM that intentionally does this all of the time.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways which could trigger a concurrency bug.

- Load your application to many more threads than you would normally expect.  Make sure this is more than enough to get 99%+ CPU.
- Run your program with a profiler enabled or the JIT disabled. This changes the timing behaviour of your application.
- Test both Java 5 and Java 6 (This is often the simplest and the best way to find a few bugs) I have not found a bug using Java 7 which didn't appear in 5/6.

For worst case JVM, try a mobile phone. (Your application probably won't work at all) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Synchronization errors are usually hard to reproduce because they depend on subtle timings between different threads, so no implementation which actually tries to "just run your program" can always be "worst possible". You can't reproduce more than one different way that two threads can interleave their instructions if you just execute these instructions once. Testing all such combinations in a single run is even less possible. One of the other posters suggested Java Pathfinder and that sounds like a good idea - but note that it's an app which runs the same code many times, so you can't really treat is as just another JVM implementation.

One more practical tip is to try and run the app on as many different JVMs as possible. Try different vendors, different versions from the same vendor, different CPU architectures and so on. A few years ago, I had experience with a heavily multithreaded app that had been developed, tested and run on Sun's JVM on Xeon CPUs where it worked very well. At one point I tried running it on IBM's J9 Java Virtual Machine on POWER architecture and at first attempt, about 2/3 of the tests failed due to synchronization errors. So, testing in different environments can be quite good at exposing hidden synchronization issues.